# Find long pressed word in Flutter

Tags: flutter, text, widget, textselection, long-press

I am displaying a text in a card, I want to add long click functionality to display more info about selected word ( the word that is long clicked ). Which text widget supports it?
SelectableText widget is not suitable, because it gives user ability to copy all of my text to somewhere else, I don't like it, I just want to find out which word is selected so I display it's meaning.

Currently I am using **Html** widget which apparently doesn't support **long pressed word**.

Comment: `GestureDetector` has `onLongPressStart` property so you can get the location where you "long "pressed, now you can use `Paragraph` API to find the position in your text closest to the given location

Comment: So I use which Widget type to display text that supports Paragraph API?

Comment: RichText widget, and use RenderParagraph api, not Paragraph as I said before

Comment: update: with `Text` it works too - `Text` uses `RenderParagraph` as its `RenderObject` as well

Comment: I am sort of newbie, how can I find which word is at Offset of a RichText

Comment: give your `Text` widget a `key: someGlobalKey` where `GloblaKey someGlobalKey = GloblaKey();` then use `RenderParagraph renderParagraph = someGlobalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
` now you have your `RenderParagraph` object

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap your `Text` widget with `GestureDetector` which has `onLongPressed` method.

```
body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Text('Long press'),
            onLongPress: () {
              // your code here
            },
          )
        )
      )
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This will fire an event without actually saying which *word* is tapped.

Comment: Hope this helps : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/5422